# Google sheets, Subtracting breaks from a range of hours

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, formulas

Say cell **A3 ='12:00 PM'** and **B3 ='6:00 PM'**

This formula will return **'6'**, for **6 hours worked**.

```
=IF(ISERROR((TIMEVALUE(B3)-TIMEVALUE(A3))*24),"0",(TIMEVALUE(B3)-TIMEVALUE(A3))*24)
```

However, I want the formula to **subtract breaks** for working a certain rage of hours. 
Say for example:

- > 4.5 hours = No change
- > between 5-7 hours = subtract .5 hour (30 mins)
- > 7+ hours = Subtract 1 hour

What could I add to the code above to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=IF(ISERROR((TIMEVALUE(B3)-TIMEVALUE(A3))*24),"0",(TIMEVALUE(B3)-TIMEVALUE(A3))*24)-LOOKUP((TIMEVALUE(B3)-TIMEVALUE(A3))*24,{0,0;5,0.5;7,1})`

Comment: Is it possible to return "0" instead of "#VALUE!" when no time has been added?

Comment: Answered my own question. For anyone that needed it. `=if(iserror(your formula here),0,your formula here)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested if statements - this is sloppy but you could copy and paste into the same cell (but maybe change the row number depending on where the data starts):

=if(if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24)<4.5,if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),if(and(if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24)>5,if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24)<7),if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24)-0.5,if(if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24)>=7,if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24)-1,if(iserror((timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24),"0",(timevalue(B1)-timevalue(A1))*24))))

A cleaner way to do this would be to create additional columns for each break interval (e.g., column C still calculates the unadjusted working time, but add column D that equals -0.5 if column C is between 5 and 7, and add column E which equals -1 if column C is greater than 7, then column F adds Columns C, D, and E)